# If Bal Tashchis and Achila Gasa would get in a fight, who would win?

Tags: food, eating, bal-tashchit-waste

There is a prohibition not to be wasteful.  There is also a prohibition not to overeat.  If a person was full, and the rest of the food was going to go to waste, is it better to discard perfectly good food, or better to overeat in order to not waste?

In order that no one attempt to avoid the underlying issue by finding a way not to waste the food, let's assume that the subject is stranded on a desert island with no other forms of life to which he could feed this food or use it for any constructive purpose.

Comment: The minhag in my shul is that bal tashchis trumps achila gasa.

Comment: בעל תשחית דגופאי עדיף

Comment: @IshPloniViKohen and YEZ -- see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=140b&format=pdf) (masechta Shabbos source for בל תשחית דגופא) and [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%AA#.D7.91.D7.9C_.D7.AA.D7.A9.D7.97.D7.99.D7.AA_.D7.93.D7.92.D7.95.D7.A4.D7.90_.D7.A2.D7.93.D7.99.D7.A3)

Comment: Athough [this](http://www.zomet.org.il/Eng/?CategoryID=264&ArticleID=256) is a much more impressive source than my second link [all from Google]

Comment: @Shokhet what did you want me to see there?

Comment: ....I gave you three links, the most important being the [first](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=140b&format=pdf), where the gemara in Shabbos says "בל תשחית דגופא עדיפא" (the others weren't as important, but the third [at first glance] appears to have a very thorough discussion of the whole topic)

Comment: @Shokhet I knew I was too vague. I only followed the last link. Perused quickly, didn't see much.  May have looked too quickly.

Comment: I did a search on the word "דגופא" on that (third) page, to see what turns up....superficially, it looked good (and is from Zomet!)

Comment: My oma always said "Your stomach is not a garbage can." Don't know if that qualifies as ancient Jewish wisdom

Comment: @Jewels - You had an "Oma" too, I see. Wise people, no? I would think that a person should not overeat b/c it's unhealthy. Even if it has no long-term effects, is indigestion really necessary b/c of Ba'al tashchis? Is that halacha really worth keeping Proctor & Gamble in business?

Comment: How do you know that there's a conflict here? Is overeating considered a constructive purpose?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I was wondering how long it was going to take someone to bring that up.  I don't know, but assuming you will be full for longer, it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I do not see any conflict between the two. One is not supposed to overeat, nor is one supposed to be wasteful. Not eating something does not mean you wasted it.

Comment: @GershonGold So can I throw out perfectly good food, for no reason?

Comment: No. You can put it away and when it spoils then dispose of it.

Comment: @GershonGold If you have a source that you can passively waste things, you could answer that.  I don't see it as being as obvious as you do.

Comment: If I had a source then I would have a answer. However I am telling you what is sensible.

Comment: @Gershon Gold a source would be the "Taanis Haraavid", (but I don't have a source for that ...yet...)

Comment: If you don't want to eat it, it's going to waste if you _do_ eat it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The gemara in Shabbos says ([140b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=140b&format=pdf))

> בל תשחית דגופא עדיף
>   Damaging (lit. בל תשחית [lit. destruction]) of one's body is more important [than בל תשחית of food]

(*translation mine*)

Seems pretty simple that if overeating is harmful to a person's body (which it is), it should be avoided even at the cost of wasting food.

Comment: Also seems clear that it is still called wasting it to not eat it (unlike the assumption of [several](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/if-bal-tashchis-and-achila-gasa-would-get-in-a-fight-who-would-win/45043#comment114652_43971) of the [comments](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/if-bal-tashchis-and-achila-gasa-would-get-in-a-fight-who-would-win/45043#comment118735_43971) on the question), even if it is the preferred choice.

Comment: @Yez Maybe not, since the gemara's case is of what to eat, and if you eat cheaper food or more expensive, by eating expensive food you are waisting money, but then it concludes that the cheaper food is bad for your body, so it is OK to waist money and buy more expensive food https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.140b.9 (tell me if I am wrong)

Comment: I think you're missing something, @hazoriz. (HI!!! It's been a while!) Y ez read (correctly, IMO) in my answer that even tho there is still BT involved in a situation where quality food (and, a fortiori, *food*), it is more important not to harm your body. The way we're reading Shabbos 140B is "the BT of your body is more important [than BT of food]."

Comment: If there would be no food-BT involved, then there's nothing nothing for body-BT to be more important than. I'm not sure what you saw in the Sefaria translation that contradicted our reading. cc @Yez

Comment: (alaihem shalom) I do not understand, to me it seemed yez wrote that from here he sees, that  **not eating** something can be B"Y,  it is just that you should not eat it if it is bad for your body. but I see no evidence that this is true. To me it seems that the B"T is from (doing an active act of destroying by) eating the expensive food, (or the active act of destroying your body by eating cheap food),  the reason I got here was because of my new question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88464/5120

Answer (score 5):

[Rabbi Binyomin Gruber](http://mk.ca/gruber.html)* told me personally that it is better to throw out food than to overeat.

<sup>* Best reference to know who he is that I could find, if someone has a better one, please share</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Per [Halachafortoday.com](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2012/04/q-page-5.html)

> Q: In reference to today’s question about baal tashchis vs. achilas
>   gasa- I always have a similar question, how can one throw out food
>   that became unusable due to kabalistic reasons (a peeled onion, food
>   under a bed that someone slept on, a drink left uncovered over night)
>   does the kabbalistic reason overrule baal tashchis which is a clear
>   aveirah? A: Peeled onions, drink left uncovered etc. is not just for
>   Kabalistic reasons. These things are brought in the Gemara, and
>   brought as Halacha in the Aruch Hashulchan, Mogen Avraham and other
>   Poskim. The reason for their being prohibited is that they are a
>   danger to the one who may eat it. As such is isn’t an Aveirah to throw
>   out something which is harmful to you. As one of my daily readers who
>   is a Talmid Chacham with Semicha reminded me upon seeing my answer,the
>   Gemara says “Bal Tashchis D’Gufa Adif- the wasting of one’s body is
>   more important than wasting food”

Comment: I suppose you held this entire discussion of Halachafortoday.com is [not sensible](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43971/if-bal-tashchis-and-achila-gasa-would-get-in-a-fight-who-would-win/44044#comment114725_43971)